# C++ dll file using 0mq

Tags: c++, sockets, dll, zeromq

I'm trying to write dll C++ library. I use 0mq to create sockets.
I have 2 files in my library: 
Library.cpp & Library.h 
In Library.h I wrote this

```
namespace Exchange
{
    class ExchangeConnection
    {

        static zmq::socket_t *sub, *req;
        static zmq::message_t message;
        ExchangeConnection();

static __declspec(dllexport) 

        long long SendPlaceMessage
            (char* user_id,

     std::tuple<long long, long long> price, long long quantity,
 bool buy, char* asset1, char* asset2, long long &error);
    }
```

But when I try to use theese sockets in Library.cpp I can't because they are only visible in class ExchangeConnection constructor

```
ExchangeConnection::ExchangeConnection(){
    zmq::socket_t sub(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    sub.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:1000");
    sub.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);
    zmq::socket_t req(context, ZMQ_REQ);
    req.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:1001");
    }
```

And other functions of ExchangeConnection class can't see theese initialized sockets

```
long long ExchangeConnection::SendCancelMessage
(long long order_id, char *user_id, long long &error)
```

when I try to build Library, I get errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class zmq::socket_t * Exchange::ExchangeConnection::sub" (?sub@ExchangeConnection@Exchange@@0PAVsocket_t@zmq@@A) C:\Users\LibraryDll\LibraryDll.obj  LibraryDll
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class `zmq::socket_t * Exchange::ExchangeConnection::req" (?req@ExchangeConnection@Exchange@@0PAVsocket_t@zmq@@A)    C:\Users\LibraryDll\LibraryDll.obj  LibraryDll`
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class zmq::message_t Exchange::ExchangeConnection::message" (?message@ExchangeConnection@Exchange@@0Vmessage_t@zmq@@A)   C:\Users\LibraryDll\LibraryDll.obj  LibraryDll
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: 1) in your constructor putting the type there shadows the static variable, so you don't actually deal with the static variable. 2) setting static variables in a constructor? are you sure that's what you want to do? constructer is per instance while static is per class

Comment: I need to make socket sub & req visible for all functions in class and to be able to send messages via them.
Firstly I tried to write 
        static zmq::socket_t sub, req;
        static zmq::message_t message;
But it didn't work.

Comment: sure, that's perfectly reasonable. I just don't think initializing them in a constructor is what you want to do

Comment: what is `context`? There's too much info missing here to help you fix your design I think

Comment: Well, I don't know where to initialize them, but I need all functions of class be able to use them. I was trying to initialize them as 
namespace Exchange
{
    class ExchangeConnection
    {

        static zmq::socket_t *sub, *req;
        static zmq::message_t message;
        ExchangeConnection();
...}
And in cpp file 
context = new zmq::context_t(1);
sub = new zmq::socket_t(context, ZMQ_SUB);

Comment: the reason I say putting it in the constructor is not what you want(i think) is that each time you instantiate an ExchangeConnection, you reset the static variables for ALL ECs

Comment: if they must be initialized based on runtime info, create a static member function in EC that can initialize those variables, and call it before you instantiate and ECs

Comment: static zmq::context_t context(1);

Comment: what is context, again? is it a runtime variable? a constant? it matters greatly in the complexity of the solution

Comment: got it - in that case initialize them at file scope in the cpp zmq::socket_t EC::sub = new blah

Comment: h: `class EC { static zmq::socket sub; }` cpp: `zmq::socket EC::sub = zmq::socket(zmq::context(1), ZMQ_SUB);`

Comment: I have this class in C#:
internal class ExchangeConnection
    {
        static private ZMQ.Context cntx;
        static private ZMQ.Socket req, sub;
        
        
        public ExchangeConnection()
        {
            cntx = new Context();
            req = cntx.Socket(ZMQ.SocketType.REQ);
            req.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:1000");
            sub = cntx.Socket(ZMQ.SocketType.SUB);
            sub.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:1001");
            sub.SetSockOpt(ZMQ.SocketOpt.SUBSCRIBE, new byte[0]);  
        } ...}

Comment: When i try to initialize like this ExchangeConnection::ExchangeConnection(){...zmq::socket_t ExchangeConnection::sub = new zmq::socket_t(context, ZMQ_SUB);...} I get Error: member Exchange:EC::sub cannot be defined in the current scope.

Comment: a c# -> c++ pitfalls: `new` is not the same. in C++ new returns a pointer, while C# it obtains an object reference from the GCed heap (i think). So try to understand their intent, but code C++ natively. if you don't declare sub as a pointer, just instantiate it at file scope. There is no such thing as file scope (i think) in C#, and everyting has to be in the class, which is why they do what they do

Comment: I think what you want is my comment that starts with h:

Comment: and by file scope i mean the only braces enveloping the code I gave for the cpp should be the namespace

Comment: I wrote like this in h file `class ExchangeConnection
 {
  static zmq::context_t context;
  static zmq::socket_t sub, req;
  static zmq::message_t message;
  ExchangeConnection();...}`
And this in cpp  `namespace Exchange{
      ExchangeConnection::ExchangeConnection(){
   zmq::context_t ExchangeConnection::context = new zmq::context_t(1);
   zmq::socket_t ExchangeConnection::sub = new zmq::socket_t(context, ZMQ_SUB);...}...}` and I get `Error: member Exchange:EC::sub cannot be defined in the current scope`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

making this an answer only for formatting purposes. your cpp is wrong:

```
namespace Exchange{ 
    ExchangeConnection::ExchangeConnection() { 
        zmq::context_t ExchangeConnection::context = new zmq::context_t(1); 
        zmq::socket_t ExchangeConnection::sub = new zmq::socket_t(context, ZMQ_SUB);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

should be

```
namespace Exchange{ 
    zmq::context_t ExchangeConnection::context = zmq::context_t(1);
    zmq::socket_t ExchangeConnection::sub = zmq::socket_t(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    ExchangeConnection::ExchangeConnection() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

note the lack of `new` as i explained the differences in `new` from C# to C++, and you didn't put the initialization at file scope like I said, but left it in the constructor.